# Detect swipes algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, swipe, detect

I want to detect from some 2D points whenever a swipe is made.
The points are coming continuously, they come from a sensor. And are in 2D space, x and y.

Are there any algorithms for this?

I've tried something like this

```
float totalDistance = 0f;
    float totalTime = 0f;
    for (int i = points.size - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        SwipePoint point1 = points.get(i); // last point added
        SwipePoint point2 = points.get(i - 1); // second last point
        totalDistance += point1.distance(point2);

        if (totalDistance > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE
                && totalTime > MIN_SWIPE_TIME) {
            // we have a swipe
            listener.onSwipe(SwipeType.DOWM, 1f);
            points.clear();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here i check if the length of the lines is bigger than a constant, and the same for the time, but is not showing anything.

Are there any algorithms for this?

Thanks.

Comment: @saadtaame is a gesture, like when you move your finger on your screen very fast , google it :)

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does not seem to identify swipe, and one of the problems is in this line:

```
totalDistance += point1.distance(point2);
```

what it does it count total length traveled by a finger and will trigger a "swipe" even if finger travels for long enough with any trajectory.

What you should do is record x and y coordinates of a first point and when you encounter a point that is far enough from a start you can trigger a swipe.

The second problem in your algorithm is that you should check if swipe time is **less** than maximum swipe time. Also, you doesn't seem to update totalTime anywhere in your code.

The code should look like this (checking only vertical swipe):

```
SwipePoint startPoint = points.get(points.size - 1);
for (int i = points.size - 2; i > 0; i--) {
    SwipePoint point = points.get(i); // last point added
    int yDiff = Math.abs(startPoint.getY() - point.getY());

    long totalTime = startPoint.getTime() - point.getTime(); 
    if yDiff > MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE
            && totalTime < MIN_SWIPE_TIME) {
        // we have a swipe
        listener.onSwipe(SwipeType.DOWM, 1f);
        points.clear();
        return;
    }
}
```